# Typescript inferring never on method parameter

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects that contain a method `f`. This method receives either a string or a number, and always returns a string. I defined its type like in the code below, however Typescript is inferring `f: (value: never) => string`, so I can't call it.

How do I make this work?

```
type ObjType = {
  f: ((value: string) => string) | ((value: number) => string)
}

const objArray: Array<ObjType> = [
  { f: (value: string) => value },
  { f: (value: number) => value.toFixed(2) }
]

console.log(objArray[0].f('1'))
console.log(objArray[1].f(1))
```

Comment: `(value: string | number) => string)`

Comment: @zerkms Ok. But then I have to check everytime if it is a string o number to use their corresponding methods.

Comment: You have to check that, because as per your description it's not known compile time.

Answer (score 4):

If the compiler only knows that a value `obj` is of type `ObjType`, then there is no value `x` for which calling `obj.f(x)` is type safe. The compiler knows that `obj.f` will *either* be something that accepts a `string`, *or* it will be something that accepts a `number`. But it doesn't know which one it is. The only safe `x` would be something that's *both* a `string` *and* a `number`: a `string & number`. But there are no such values; the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `string` and `number` is [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  That's why the compiler infers `never` as the method parameter for `f`.

You [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `objArray` as type `Array<ObjType>`.  Doing so explicitly threw away any information the compiler may have had about the particular elements of the array literal; all it knows from then on is that each element of `objArray` is an `ObjType`. And so it will not let you call the `f()` method on its elements. Generally speaking, if you annotate a variable like `const variable: Type = ...`, and if `Type` is not itself a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (and `Array<ObjType>` is not a union), the compiler will only know that `variable` is of type `Type`; it will not keep track of any extra information.

---

If you'd like to be able to call the `f` method on elements of `objArray`, you will have to give the compiler more information. One way to do so is to remove the type annotation and instead use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which sort of does the opposite: you are explicitly asking the compiler to remember as much specific type information as possible about the value you are assigning to the variable:

```
const objArray = [
  { f: (value: string) => value },
  { f: (value: number) => value.toFixed(2) }
] as const;

/* const objArray: readonly [{
  readonly f: (value: string) => string;
 }, {
  readonly f: (value: number) => string;
 }] */
```

Here you can see that the compiler infers that `objArray` is a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) of exactly two elements, the first of which has a `string`-taking `f` method, and the second of which has a `number`-taking `f` method. Now you can do this with no error:

```
console.log(objArray[0].f('1')); // okay
console.log(objArray[1].f(1)); // okay
```

Hooray. But this might not be very useful in practice; presumably, there's a reason you put these objects into an array in the first place; if you wanted to keep track of each object individually you could just have assigned them to different variables in the first place. There's still no way to take an *arbitrary* `ObjType`-like object and call its `f()` method.

---

A function by itself is not really something that contains enough information at runtime to determine what type of parameter it expects. It's like an unlabeled bottle of pills. I suppose you could try to call the function with some test input and catch any errors that are thrown, but that's bad practice; it's like taking the pills and "seeing what happens". Instead, it would be better if values of type `ObjType` are explicitly *marked* with the information you need to choose what to do with it. You want a label on your pill bottle.

The canonical way to do this in TypeScript is to make `ObjType` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
type StringTaker = {
  takes: "string";
  f: (value: string) => string;
}

type NumberTaker = {
  takes: "number";
  f: (value: number) => string;
}

type ObjType = StringTaker | NumberTaker;
```

Here, an object of type `ObjType` will have a `takes` property whose value is a string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of either `"string"` or `"number"`. By checking that property, the compiler can use the outcome to know what kind of parameter the `f` method expects:

```
function doSomethingWithObjArray(arr: Array<ObjType>) {
  arr.forEach(o => console.log(o.takes === "string" ? o.f("1") : o.f(1)); // no error
}
```

Of course, this means that `objArray` needs to include the label in each element:

```
const objArray: Array<ObjType> = [
  { takes: "string", f: value => value }, 
  { takes: "number", f: value => value.toFixed(2) }
]
```

(but notice that the `value` callback parameter is contextually typed). And now this works without having to keep track of the order of elements of an array:

```
doSomethingWithObjArray(objArray); // 1, 1.00
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZEBLYAXDwDyATgCYQGYDmAksAGYD2BYIW6dwSA3gLABQvSSeGyhYkdAEYArAIIECIAJ5IAvEgDa-AZyQ0AXEgAUANxAAbAK4R9IssHIBKFQD4kJi8gC+AGk0COO-WMzS31gczBxUkdlFzdLADosOgAxdAAPCCIDACZHD00AXSQQKEFhLABuXk0AegAqMuARMSlZeQV9AggQIjZTJTVuHi0kLp6+pT1DOKskGwpol3m7KuGBb05fUe7e4H6A6eDZsIio5zmsW3JVrQ8iuprqtaEmulMIeNM6cgMJGTlFGoAAwFeI0AwAcgAjBD7PZNC8oG8Pl8fn82oCoaDwVC4U98nweKBILAEMgACLoKDwMhgTDMTIAVWArHYQ00WAUMGQAGVLhQACogADWpBUmzWAhwoqg+gARMtyHKblopkF3NZ+XZFhcriqCRyucgAHLhSIEIWigjioYjaXQeUnc3KrZqmahM1nGK6ij6p5So1IPBSAWB1R8q6WsUAHyQptOFpFpFWCPKLX+7X0GIUAB5g5JQ9yXKoNJLtPbZUgFVqlV4DjNzg3vFt-BXHZ6CHK61MG96ZokUulMjk8oV-TpzMB4Cw2Ehejy6JAsAALCgAdXQK-z2YMIDkWYBufzhYgTkctq0e4IYIYAFEEMvfudEcjPt9fokk6VlD+q4q5UgAD8YhggYcpQnKjj6HQoG4vYfqEgI86LhAK7rpuy7boevytIe8FIDUNRIFCdZQvEQJAviTxAA)